# Unable to enter a response automatically using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to use `.bat` file (Windows) to automate a registration process.
Below is the content of my batch file:

```
C:
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\SSL_Client
admin -r
echo n
echo mithun
echo 12339-asdda-wewew
```

It works until `admin -r` which prompts user to enter Y/N
However above code doesnt work..
I am a newbie and sorry for such a basic question

Comment: have you tried `echo y| admin -r`

Comment: Hi ... Yes.. that didn't work but the solution suggested by Stephan did the trick.. However it does give issue because of the  number of parameters..

Comment: you may also build a vbscrit/batch quimera with sendkeys/sleep. surf this place and you'll find lot of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script runs `admin -r`, and *when finished*, continues with the next line, which echoes `n` to the console (where you don't need it).

There is a trick to give inputs to an executable (which may or may not work - depends on the executable): pipe the information to it:

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\SSL_Client"
(
  echo n
  echo mithun
  echo 12339-asdda-wewew
)|admin -r
```

Comment: Just one more question Stephan.. what does "cd /d" signify.. The command window closes after inputting everything. Is it because of "/d". Any other option to keep window open ?

Comment: Your window closes because the script ended, `CD`'s `/D` option has nothing to do with it. To find out what the `/D` option does, open a Command Prompt window and read the usage information `CD /?`.

Comment: and to keep the window open, just add a `pause`.